# React native calendar issue while using it in a view and adjusting it according to view height and width

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native calendar isn't fitting properly in the view, especially on small devices. As you can see in the image I'm showing you, the calendar displays three rows, but on larger screens, it shows completely without any issues, leaving some space below. How can I adjust it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eeqD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqYPT.png)

``<View style={{ width: wd * 0.87, flex: 0.48 }}>
<View style={{ flex: 0.15, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
<Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000000',  fontSize:isLandscapeMode?moderateScale(13): moderateScale(17) }}>Select Date

```
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#EBF3FF', borderRadius:isLandscapeMode?moderateScale(10): moderateScale(20), overflow: 'hidden', flex: 0.85,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center' }}>
          <Calendar
            minDate={new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]}
            showSixWeeks={true}
            showWeekNumbers={false}
            onDayPress={(day) => handleDateSelect(day)}
            markedDates={{
              [selected]: { selected: true, disableTouchEvent: true, selectedDotColor: 'orange' },
            }}
            style={{backgroundColor:'green',height:verticalScale(200),width:wd*0.87}}
            theme={{
              calendarBackground: 'transparent',
              arrowColor: '#848A95',
              selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
              selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#94ADFD',
              textMonthFontSize: moderateScale(14),
              dayTextColor: 'black',
              textDayFontSize: moderateScale(12),
              textDayHeaderFontWeight: 'bold',
              'stylesheet.calendar.header': {
                dayHeader: {
                  color: 'black',
                },

              },
              // 'stylesheet.calendar.main': {
              //   week: {
              //     marginTop: 10, // Reduce margin between weeks
              //     marginBottom: 10
              //   }
              // },


            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>`
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Calendar component will render full month calendar in a View, If you need to show specific week only, you may **use ExpandableCalendar** from same library.

The reason for not fitting in your view is it require some minimum height to render header for calendar, week day names and 4 or 5 weeks below the as body of calendar.

Have a try by using **WeekCalendar** or **ExpandableCalendar** for better flexibility as per your requirements.

Comment: No i want full calender not only week.
On big screens it is showing full even some space remain at bottom but in small devices it is cutting down the view and showing only 3 rows here instead of 6

Comment: Can you please add some changings in my code so that full calendar is being shown for all screens

Comment: I don't think that is possible to resize calendar according to screen size..
You may manage it like above way..

Comment: Okay?Can we use react native calendar picker ?

Comment: Yeah, in this case the picker would be great tool to use.
Have a try of https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker

Comment: But its height and width are also dependent on each other

Comment: I think, you'll need a button or a design look like a calendar to open this calendar picker, which won't take that much size as it will opened inside new picker window..

Comment: But according to my ui only react native calendars supports